# Aggregate & Sort by Inner Array in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I'm pretty new to mongoDB. Please bear with me.

I have a collection called Users which contains list of Roles. A user can have multiple roles, therefore roles are listed in an array. I want to sort the users by their role names.

User structure looks like this,

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5bc910a39e53b62c7d4c4e62"),
  "_class": "User",
  "userName": "John",
  "fullName": "Doe",
  "roles": [
    DBRef("roles",
    ObjectId("5d5cf8ceb3773255b54d18c6")),
    DBRef("roles",
    ObjectId("5d5cf8ceb3773255b54d18c7"))
  ]
}
```

**Classes**

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String fullName;
    private boolean active;
    @DBRef
    private List<Role> roles;
  //constructor, getter, setter
}



@Document(collection = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

//constructor, getter, setter

}
```

I have tried the following,

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 setCriteriaReadOnlyIsNullOrReadOnlyIsFalse(criteria);
 criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("<condition>").is(<"condition_data">));

 AggregationOperation userMatch = Aggregation.match(criteria);
 LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
                .from("roles")
                .localField("roles.id")
                .foreignField("id")
                .as("rolesAgg");
 AggregationOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "rolesAgg.name");
 AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project("id", "userName", "fullName","roles");


TypedAggregation<User> aggregation = newAggregation(User.class, userMatch, lookupOperation, sort, project);

return mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, User.class).getMappedResults();
```

This produces results, but unable to sort since the **rolesAgg** is a array of objects. This is how the rolesAgg displays per user.

```
"rolesAgg": [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d5cf8ceb3773255b54d18c3"),
    "name": "Super Admin"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d5cf8ceb3773255b54d18c5"),
    "name": "Customer Service"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d5cf8ceb3773255b54d18c4"),
    "name": "Admin"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to extract the **rolesAgg.name** into an array and they sort using that? I'm stuck. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sort when objects are inside the array.

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$rolesAgg"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "rolesAgg.name": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      username: {
        "$first": "$username"
      },
      "fullname": {
        "$first": "$fullname"
      },
      rolesAgg: {
        $push: "$rolesAgg"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So you need to do

To flat the array

```
Aggregation.unwind("$rolesAgg")
```

To sort by name

```
Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "rolesAgg.name")
```

To group all back

```
Aggregation.group("_id)
    .first("username").as("username")
    .first("fullname").as("fullname")
    .push("rolesAgg").as("rolesAgg")
```

respectively.

Note : If you have more fields while grouping, consider it also

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z6J8q6Vb1Kr)

Comment: Hi varman, thank you for the detail explanation. It's sorts the roles inside the array now. But not the user. Is it also possible to sort the user based on the sorted role names?

Comment: Yes you can, where does role name come from?

Comment: rolesAgg.name is the role name. But sorting it doesn't sort the user. https://mongoplayground.net/p/H9kyJ0pyxE_

Comment: try this https://mongoplayground.net/p/5XJL22KwLu7 U sorted the array and grouped, Username or full name is not in array, so you can do normal sorting